# How Do I Delete created and appended element now

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've Created element 'li' and appended two other elements(div and button) in it by creating them too.. Now when it is appended in the DOM, I want it to also dynamically be deleted when clicking Delete button, also I've grabbed all those buttons in btnid variable through which that 'li' item is to be deleted but Now I'm not getting How would I addEventListener to those buttons, If I normally add btnid.addEvent....... then it throws error coz it isn't defined yet as there's no element until an element is added dynamically.

```js
let input = document.querySelector('#addinput')
let btn = document.querySelector('#addbtn')
let listcontainer = document.querySelector('#listcontainer')

let btnid;
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let inpVal = input.value
    if (inpVal.length != 0) {
        let html = `<li class="margin5pxall pad5pxall"><div>${inpVal}</div><button class="btn delete">Delete</button>`
        listcontainer.innerHTML += html
        btnid = listcontainer.getElementsByTagName('button')
        console.log(btnid);
        input.classList.remove('red')
    } else {
        input.classList.add('red')
    }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="mainBox flecCol bordernRad">
        <div class="flexCol margin5pxall bordernRad mainHead">
            <h1 class="textAlign head margin5pxall">Book List</h1>
            <div class="flexRow margin5pxX">
                <input type="text" class="inp margin5pxall" placeholder="Search">
                <button class="btn">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="list margin5pxall bordernRad">
            <ul id="listcontainer"></ul>
        </div>
        <div class="flexCol bordernRad margin5pxall lastHead">
            <h1 class="textAlign head margin5pxY">Add a New Book</h1>
            <div class="flexRow margin5pxX">
                <input type="text" class="inp margin5pxall" id="addinput" placeholder="Book Name">
                <button class="btn" id="addbtn">Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
<script src="index.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [parentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement) and `remove` with an `onclick` function to your `delete` button. This way only the item you `clicked` will be removed.

> In the `onclick()` function `this` refers to as which element we have clicked on

Run snippet below to see it working.

```js
let input = document.querySelector('#addinput')
let btn = document.querySelector('#addbtn')
let listcontainer = document.querySelector('#listcontainer')

let btnid;
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let inpVal = input.value
  if (inpVal.length != 0) {
    let html = `<li class="margin5pxall pad5pxall"><div>${inpVal}</div><button class="btn delete" onclick="removeItem(this)">Delete</button>`
    listcontainer.innerHTML += html
    //clear input
    input.value = ''
    //Add class
    input.classList.remove('red')
  } else {
    input.classList.add('red')
  }
})

//Remove Item
function removeItem(event) {
  event.parentElement.remove()
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="mainBox flecCol bordernRad">
    <div class="flexCol margin5pxall bordernRad mainHead">
      <h1 class="textAlign head margin5pxall">Book List</h1>
      <div class="flexRow margin5pxX">
        <input type="text" class="inp margin5pxall" placeholder="Search">
        <button class="btn">Search</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list margin5pxall bordernRad">
      <ul id="listcontainer"></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="flexCol bordernRad margin5pxall lastHead">
      <h1 class="textAlign head margin5pxY">Add a New Book</h1>
      <div class="flexRow margin5pxX">
        <input type="text" class="inp margin5pxall" id="addinput" placeholder="Book Name">
        <button class="btn" id="addbtn">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
<script src="index.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm a newbie in javascript so i was having a problem

Comment: @SamarthMittal No worries. Would you  mind upvotting the answer if i have helped you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.createElement` to add the elements instead, on which you can add event listeners.

```
const li = document.createElement('li');
li.className = "margin5pxall pad5pxall";
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.textContent = inpVal;
const delBtn = document.createElement('button');
delBtn.className = "btn delete";
delBtn.textContent = "Delete";
li.appendChild(div);
li.appendChild(delBtn);
delBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    listcontainer.removeChild(li);
});
listcontainer.appendChild(li);
```

Demo:

```js
let input = document.querySelector('#addinput')
let btn = document.querySelector('#addbtn')
let listcontainer = document.querySelector('#listcontainer')

let btnid;
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let inpVal = input.value
    if (inpVal.length != 0) {
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.className = "margin5pxall pad5pxall";
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.textContent = inpVal;
        const delBtn = document.createElement('button');
        delBtn.className = "btn delete";
        delBtn.textContent = "Delete";
        li.appendChild(div);
        li.appendChild(delBtn);
        delBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
            listcontainer.removeChild(li);
        });
        listcontainer.appendChild(li);
        input.classList.remove('red')
    } else {
        input.classList.add('red')
    }
})
```

```html
<div class="mainBox flecCol bordernRad">
  <div class="flexCol margin5pxall bordernRad mainHead">
    <h1 class="textAlign head margin5pxall">Book List</h1>
    <div class="flexRow margin5pxX">
      <input type="text" class="inp margin5pxall" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list margin5pxall bordernRad">
    <ul id="listcontainer"></ul>
  </div>
  <div class="flexCol bordernRad margin5pxall lastHead">
    <h1 class="textAlign head margin5pxY">Add a New Book</h1>
    <div class="flexRow margin5pxX">
      <input type="text" class="inp margin5pxall" id="addinput" placeholder="Book Name">
      <button class="btn" id="addbtn">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm a newbie in javascript so i was having  a problem